# Why am I getting chunked stream ended unexpectedly when I use HttpClient?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

The problem only seems to occur with "large" files I'm trying to post.

My code looks like this:

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);

File input = new File(filePathname);
RequestEntity entity = new FileRequestEntity(input, "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

method.setRequestEntity(entity);
method.setRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=xyzzy")

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("userid", "pw");

client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope("hostname", port, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), defaultcreds);

 try {
    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        throw new Exception("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
    }

    // Read the response body.
    byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
    return new String(responseBody);
 }
 catch (HttpException e) {
    System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;

 }
 catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;

 }
 finally {
     // Release the connection.
     method.releaseConnection();
 }
```

The exception text looks like this:

```
Fatal transport error: chunked stream ended unexpectedly
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: chunked stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSizeFromInputStream(ChunkedInputStream.java:252)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:176)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:108)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBody(HttpMethodBase.java:690)
```

I get a similar exception whether I use getResponseBody() or getResponseBodyAsStream().

I shouldn't be getting much data back, but I am posting over 200mb of data.

Comment: I meant to mention the exception occurs when the code performs method.getResponseBody()

Comment: Trying to figure out how to add the text of the exception I'm seeing...

Comment: Big POST you've done there. How long does that upload take? (Could it be just a timeout?)

Comment: Several minutes, and maybe there's a timeout.  I've been "playing" with the code a little more and found that it had no problem with a 100MB file, and then no problem with a 175MB file, so I got new copies of the files I was having problems with, and put them in the same folder as the files I wasn't having problems with, and all of a sudden they uploaded without any chunked stream ended unexpectedly exceptions.

Comment: Hmm that's very odd. So something else is going on and it's just ending up triggering the server to get fed up and close the underlying stream on you. Tracking this sort of problem down to something specific that can be fixed can be really hard.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should just try the HttpComponents HTTPClient.  I don't really understand the inconsistency right now of what I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to make this problem go away by altering the length of the file name value specified in the PostMethod's requestHeader.  I had been including an encoded version of the full file pathname in the request header.  Through trial and error I found that success or failure of the file I was "posting" seemed to depend on the folder it was in.  A long folder file pathname wasn't working while a short one, albeit with the same file, was.  So I eliminated the path name from the request header and only started including the file name and I'm no longer seeing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be old , Can save some time.....
I got this error where Server is in Python and Clinet is Java.

1st -

> Error from Java Client "Error while sending data over http java.io.IOException: CRLF expected at end of chunk: 79/82
>   java.io.IOException: CRLF expected at end of chunk: 79/82"

2nd -

> Error from Java Clinet "Error while sending data over http java.io.IOException: chunked stream ended unexpectedly
>   java.io.IOException: chunked stream ended unexpectedly"

Both the errors got resolved by changing the ok response with chunked stream size

One with issues -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nServer: Jetty(6.1.26)\r\n\r\nDE\r\n
```

Resolved with -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 20000\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nServer: Jetty(6.1.26)\r\n\r\n229\r\n
```

Note = nDE is replaced with n229

Comment: Hello Malasani, could you add a code block to your error codes and a phrase or two to explain your changes? Thanks!